# Reference request - exponential decay with the Laplace transform

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, laplace-transform

Let $f \colon [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be a continuous function and define its Laplace transform by
$$\mathcal{L}f(\lambda) = \int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-\lambda t}\, dt, \quad \forall \lambda > 0.$$
Are there results giving sufficient conditions on $\mathcal{L}f$ which guarantee that $f$ decays exponentially fast at infinity? I am mainly looking for conditions on the regularity and/or decay of the Laplace transform. I am not at all familiar with this subject so any reference is greatly appreciated.